# Сохранение discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Делаю бота Discord. Увидел в Discord боте "MEE6" создание кастомных команд и соответственно их сохранение, захотел сделать хотя-бы сохранение настроек. В боте есть словарь с серверными настройками, которые можно настраивать с помощью команд.

```
configs = {
    'logDM': 939064043740729364,
    'logBot': 937207414623703080,
    'welcomeChannel': 937264634262618122,
    'filtered_words': ['some', 'filtered', 'words']
}
```

**Моя задача - сделать, чтобы настройки, устанавливаемые боту на сервере, сохранялись и в cfg, т.е. после отключения бота - они не пропадали, однако не представляю реализации этой затеи. Пытался гуглить, но даже гугля, не нашел ответа на свой вопрос, поэтому пришел сюда.**

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если у вас своя система хранения данных, то на вряд ли вам удастся нагуглить что-то готовое. Ну, по логике, получение каналов и списка `filtered_words` нужно разместить в функции `on_ready()` - чтобы эти данные подгружались один раз, при запуске бота

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать запись конфига в файл!
Вот кусочек кода как это сделать:

```
lines = ["one", "two", "three"]
with open(r"D:\Папка\cnf.txt", "w") as file:
for line in lines:
    file.write(line + '\n')
```